# Pycharm 3.4.1 CE doctests: can't run for directory

Tags: python, testing, pycharm

When I try to run all doctests for directory I receive

```
/usr/bin/python3.4 /home/d9k/soft/pycharm-community-3.4.1/helpers/pycharm/docrunner.py /home/d9k/pr/bkuppr/
Testing started at 12:05 AM ...
usage: .........
docrunner.py: error: invalid choice: '/home/d9k/pr/bkuppr/' (choose from 'run', 'restore', 'edit', 'test') ......
Empty test suite.
```

When I run doctests for one specific file docrunner find them and execute correctly.

How to setup doctests for running all tests from folder properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there was a bug in module docrunner.py: some commands were not in

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

block, so they were executed and crushed tests run.